# Providing *implicit* conversion operator for template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, template-specialization

I have a templated `sparse_vector<T>` class, and I am also using Boost UBLAS.  How would I provide *implicit* conversions between `sparse_vector<double>` and `boost::numeric::ublas::compressed_vector<double>`?

I would also like to provide similar conversions between `std::vector<double>` and `boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double>`.

(I am using gcc 4.4 with C++0x enabled.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume that there's an iterator constructor for these types.  If that assumption is accurate then it would be as simple as writing something like so:

```
template < typename OutputVector, typename InputVector >
OutputVector vector_cast(InputVector const& input)
{
  return OutputVector(input.begin(), input.end());
}
```

Use like: `compressed_vector<double> vect = vector_cast<compressed_vector<double> >(my_sparse_vector);`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  I'm actually asking if an implicit conversion can be written, so that I can use std::vector<...> in a context where boost::...::vector is expected.  (I've edited the question to make that clearer.)

Comment: That can't be done.  You can override each such function and then call the original with the above explicit "cast" but that's as close as you'll ever get without actually altering the objects in question.

Comment: Thanks.  I just wanted to make sure it was impossible.

Comment: Is it possible to have a member function in a templated class that is conditionally added depending on the templated type?

Comment: Yes.  Have a look at boost::enable_if